# How do I make a top in discord.py using repl.it database

Tags: python, database, discord.py, replit

So basically I have some db keys (I use the XP prefix and the user's Id's: db["XP{user.id}"]). Each key contains an integer which is the XP earned in the server.
How do I make a list out of the keys and sort the list? (like a XP top)
The final output should look like:

> 1# Denis#1627 : 5382XP

> 2# Discord#5262 : 5000XP

also I'm sorry about any mistake, I'm new on stackoverflow

Comment: You could convert the dict into a list and then use the python sort() feature, see more details here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort

Comment: That's actually smart, I overthinked this. A search keys by prefix converted to a list and sorted by criteria would do the trick. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

The `db.keys()` function will return a set (like an array but it's unordered, iterable and have not duplicate items) with all **the keys that you have stored** in replit database.

For example:

```
database_keys = db.keys()
print(database_keys)
```

Expected output:

```
{'XP0000', 'XP1111', 'XP2222', 'server_name', 'server_admin', 'etc'}
```

If you store **other keys** that aren't storing the XP of users, and only want **get the ones with XP prefix**, you could use `db.prefix(prefix)` that recieves a prefix has a parameter. And it's going to **return a tuple with all keys that start with the prefix**. (The prefix must be an string)

For example:

```
XP_database_keys = db.prefix("XP") # will return all the database keys that start with "XP"
print(XP_database_keys)
```

Expected output:

```
('XP0000', 'XP1111', 'XP2222')
```

After getting the keys with any of the methods, you could with the same key get the user's id with discord.py, then getting their values "amount of XP" and then order from smallest to largest value and send it in a discord embed to your server.

Hope I've been helpful, have a nice day!